# Merge sorting algorithm in Python for two sorted lists - trouble constructing for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to create an algorithm to merge two ordered lists into a larger ordered list in Python. Essentially I began by trying to isolate the minimum elements in each list and then I compared them to see which was smallest, because that number would be smallest in the larger list as well. I then appended that element to the empty larger list, and then deleted it from the original list it came from. I then tried to loop through the original two lists doing the same thing. Inside the "if" statements, I've essentially tried to program the function to append the remainder of one list to the larger function if the other is/becomes empty, because there would be no point in asking which elements between the two lists are comparatively smaller then.

```
def merge_cabs(cab1, cab2):
    for (i <= all(j) for j in cab1):
        for (k <= all(l) for l in cab2):
            if cab1 == []:
                newcab.append(cab2)
            if cab2 == []:
                newcab.append(cab1)
            else:
                    k = min(min(cab1), min(cab2))
                    newcab.append(k)
                    if min(cab1) < min(cab2):
                        cab1.remove(min(cab1))
                    if min(cab2) < min(cab1):
                        cab2.remove(min(cab2))
    print(newcab)


cab1 = [1,2,5,6,8,9]
cab2 = [3,4,7,10,11]
newcab = []
merge_cabs(cab1, cab2)
```

I've had a bit of trouble constructing the for-loop unfortunately. One way I've tried to isolate the minimum values was as I wrote in the two "for" lines. Right now, Python is returning "SyntaxError: invalid syntax," pointing to the colon in the first "for" line. Another way I've tried to construct the for-loop was like this:

```
def merge_cabs(cabs1, cabs2):
    for min(i) in cab1:
        for min(j) in cab2:
```

I've also tried to write the expression all in one line like this:

```
def merge_cabs(cab1, cab2):
    for min(i) in cabs1 and min(j) in cabs2:
```

and to loop through a copy of the original lists rather than looping through the lists themselves, because searching through the site, I've found that it can sometimes be difficult to remove elements from a list you're looping through. I've also tried to protect the expressions after the "for" statements inside various configurations of parentheses. If someone sees where the problem(s) lies, it would really be great if you could point it out, or if you have any other observations that could help me better construct this function, I would really appreciate those too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple-minded solution to this that uses only very basic Python operations:

```
def merge_cabs(cab1, cab2):
    len1 = len(cab1)
    len2 = len(cab2)

    i = 0
    j = 0
    newcab = []

    while i < len1 and j < len2:
        v1 = cab1[i]
        v2 = cab2[j]
        if v1 <= v2:
            newcab.append(v1)
            i += 1
        else:
            newcab.append(v2)
            j += 1

    while i < len1:
        newcab.append(cab1[i])
        i += 1

    while j < len2:
        newcab.append(cab2[j])
        j += 1

    return newcab
```

Things to keep in mind:

1. You should *not have any nested loops*.  Merging two sorted lists is typically used to implement a merge sort, and the merge step should be linear.  I.e., the algorithm should be O(n).
2. You need to walk both lists together, choosing the smallest value at east step, and advancing *only* the list that contains the smallest value.  When one of the lists is consumed, the remaining elements from the unconsumed list are simply appended in order.
3. You should not be calling `min` or `max` etc. in your loop, since that will effectively introduce a nested loop, turning the merge into an O(n**2) algorithm, which ignores the fact that the lists are known to be sorted.
4. Similarly, you should not be calling any external sort function to do the merge, since that will result in an O(n*log(n)) merge (or worse, depending on the sort algorithm), and again ignores the fact that the lists are known to be sorted.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is very nice and I've found the notes you've written at the bottom very helpful as well

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there's a function in the (standard library) heapq module for doing exactly this, [heapq.merge](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge); if this is a real problem (rather than an exercise), you want to use that one instead.

If this is an exercise, there are a couple of points:

- You'll need to use a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop:

  ```
  while cab1 or cab2:
  ```

  This will keep repeating the body while there are any items in either of your source lists.
- You probably shouldn't delete items from the source lists; that's a relatively expensive operation. In addition, on the balance having a `merge_lists` function destroy its arguments would be unexpected.

  Within the loop you'll refer to `cab1[i1]` and `cab2[i2]` (and, in the condition, to `i1 < len(cab1)`).

(By the time I typed out the explanation, [Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5460719/tom-karzes) typed out the corresponding code in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68241953/683329)...)

Comment: Thank you for the reference to heapq module! Also, the points you've written at the bottom are very useful to me too and I really appreciate them